# How to resolve the error "ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'"

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift3

I get the error:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

On the following code:

```
let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
guard   let jsonDictionary = jsonObject as? [NSObject: AnyObject], 
        let photos = jsonDictionary["photos"] as? [String: AnyObject], // this line is giving the error
        let photosArray = photos["photo"] as [[String: AnyObject]] else {
 print("Error")
}
```

Previous posts have suggested that I change the type from `[String: AnyObject]` to `[AnyObjectHashable: Any]`. This hasn't fixed the error. Can someone explain why this error is occurring and how it can be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace this, for making dictionary in swift 3 you can use like [String: Any] instead of [String: AnyObject]

```
let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
guard   let jsonDictionary = jsonObject as? [String: Any],
    let photos = jsonDictionary["photos"] as? [String: AnyObject], // this line is giving the error
    let photosArray = photos["photo"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
        print("Error")
}
print(jsonDictionary)
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed all to Any and AnyHashable.

Comment: @grabury In your question you said you tried exactly that and it didn't work. What made it work now?

Comment: @HAS the error was on that particular line so I only changed that line. I then changed all occurrences to AnyHashable and Any

Comment: It is better to use Any than AnyObject from now